# If I can design a neural network to output Y given X, and I can convert Y back to X, is there any way to learn from this?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, autoencoders, gan

Consider a scenario in which I use a deep neural network to output Y given X (this can also be an encoder-decoder pair: X->Y). If I have a method to convert Y->X (known technique, let's call the output X'), can I learn from this by comparing X' with X? That is, without any additional data, can I tune my neural network to better predict Y for the given X.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question itself say the answer. You can use auto-encoder and usually euclidean distance is used to compare the reconstruction errors. And you can find more resources on line. Here I provide the Theano implementation of [Stacking De-noise Autoencoder](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/dA.html) and also [wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoencoder).

But notice, when applying auto-encoder, it's better to avoid trivial solution where the identical transformation happens. You can either add noises to training data or regularizer term to make the weight parameter sparse.